# CakePhp, Xampp & SSL "Internal error has occured"

Tags: cakephp, ssl, xampp, shopify

Im trying to set up an SSL connection on my localhost XAMPP. Ive done this before, and had it working, but this time around I have trouble with the SSL connection I guess, cause I doubt its about the code since it was something that worked on before. And there have not been any changes since then. Im using virtual hosts with SSL on only one page. When I try and connect to it, it shows me an error on cakephp, but gives me no information about what the error is. Here is a Screnshot:

[image]

Also On my Xampp I have the next configuration for it to work with SSL:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\Bebe2go api"
    ServerName bebe2goapi.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\server.key"
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\Bebe2go api">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Im using a Shopify login plugin for the login and calls to Shopify. Right now its not working, but Im not sure why this is happeing. I dont think the error is on the code, but Ive tried quite a few options with no luck at all. Any ideas where I could start to look for a solution for this?

A quick side note here: The favicon from the page is being replaced by the Xampp favicon. Instead of the normal Cakephp icon which should show. Im not sure if this has anything to do with the trouble im haveing. But its worth noting.

If you need any more information please do ask :D

EDIT: 
Acutally I just noticed, I get the next error on the cakephp errorlog:

```
    2016-04-13 00:25:16 Error: [CurlException] SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Request URL: /shopify/install?code=a547ef8d8ceb1470f89a23bd4318fa4d&hmac=c95ccf2fc00221b4e1f15acb645ab7009bcf99ba0bf2eb399c3e105184bdeaad&shop=bebe2go.myshopify.com&signature=f1df3f9788935385932ff577961dcf70&timestamp=1460499916
```

Comment: have you checked the errorlogs of cake, php and the webserver?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just solved my problem, hehehe Apparently I was not pointing to the curl.cainfo from the php.ini wasnt pointing to the right direcction. This made the problem harder to solve cause the error didnt include a description for this error. All I had to do was put the right URL on the curl.cainfo in the php.ini from my xampp program and presto.

The rest was done right.